# JQuery check value of checkbox OnLoad

Tags: jquery

Im using SharePoint 2010 and have created a CEWP that displays fields associated with a checkbox when it is clicked and has a check.  I need to check the value of the checkbox on the load as well and I'm not catching it for some reason.  What am I doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    alert('onload');
    //Hides /Shows Fields on load?
    if (("input[title$='Phone Data Collection']").is(':checked'))
    //if (("input[title$='Phone Data Collection']").checked
    {
        alert('inside show for phone');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition of "if" is missing the character **$** or the word **jQuery**, that identifies you are using a jquery selector for the element.

Try to replace it for:

```
if ($("input[title$='Phone Data Collection']").is(':checked'))
```

Comment: I'm The Edge and that worked perfectly!  Thank you!